# Similar Product Pages and Properly Using Canonical Property

Tags: seo, google, canonical-url, best-practices

I have several products on my website that I am trying to decide if I should use the URL Canonical property on. The reason is because several of the pages will have very near identical information on them. The thing I am worried about though is I also want to use the Product Schema markup so that it stands out more with the MSRP, Rating and Review number.

My plan is to have a main product page think of it as a grouped product. Example if I were selling tables and they are constructed almost identical except one has a built in filing cabinet. The main product page would talk about how the product is built and mention it has an option of a built in filing cabinet. On the same main product page there would be two links to the individual product for specific specs and pictures so the customer does not get confused. (note: there can be main product pages with up to eight options so there could be up to eight individual product links with nearly identical information)

These individual product pages would have the rating, price, reviews on them but the actual marketing content would be nearly identical, so I figured by using the Canonical Property I would avoid any duplicate content issues, however I do not know if when Google and other search engines see this if they will basically ignore these individual pages and the ratings, etc. on them.

My questions are:

1. Is this using the Canonical URL Property correctly?
2. Will search engines ignore the schema markup on the individual pages if i go this route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is one way people canonicalise duplicate product pages on ecommerce and is a valid way to use it. As long as the content on the product page is identical, or a large part of the content is exact and appears on both pages. If the pages are not extremely close in exact words, the canonical designation might be disregarded by search engines.
2. For the most part yes. When you canonicalise one page to another, the canonicalised page will over time be removed from the SERPS. So although the page still might be crawled by Google and the tags seen, they won't have any effect as they won't be appearing in the SERPS once the page is dropped from the SERPS,